# npm ERR! missing script: start when running docker compose up

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, npm, docker-compose

I am trying to run mongodb with a Node.js app on a docker container. However, every time I run the docker compose up command, I receive the following error:

> npm ERR! missing script: start

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.11-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5500

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: ians-mongo
    restart: always
    build: ./vidly
    ports:
      - '5500:5500'
    external_links:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - '27012:27017'

  mongo-express:
    container_name: mongo-express
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - '8083:8081'
```

And here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "vidly",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "config": "^3.3.9",
    "debug": "^4.3.4",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "helmet": "^7.0.0",
    "joi": "^17.9.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22"
  }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my folder structure:

[image]

I'm wondering if it has something do with the dockerfile not being able to find the package.json file, or possibly the value for the build property in the yml file being incorrect.

Comment: Are the `docker-compose.yml` file, `Dockerfile`, and `package.json` all in the same directory?  The screenshot suggests that, but the Compose setup limits the image build to a `vidly` subdirectory.

Comment: Yes they are all in the same directory. Should I just have . for build?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense here.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still results in the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the build statement for your app in the docker-compose file. It is currently looking at a "vidly" subdirectory, that doesn't exist in your screenshot. You could add a dockerfile statement which would make sure the correct dockerfile is seen.

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: ians-mongo
    restart: always
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '5500:5500'
    external_links:
      - mongo
```

Comment: I tried with jus "." after build, and I got the same error. I tried to modify my yml file based on your example, but I get this message: services.app Additional property dockerfile is not allowed

Comment: Yea i messed up my syntax with the dockerfile statement. I updated the answer.

Comment: I updated my dockerfile to reflect your edit, but unfortunately, it looks like I'm still getting the same error. Although it occurred to me: would I need to run docker compose build again first before trying to run the container?

Comment: You could also remove the asterisk from the copy statement. I usually only copy the package.json file

Comment: You probably should do a build again

Comment: Actually I think that was it. I just needed to rebuild the container after making the changes to the Dockerfile and yml file. Thank you!